# App' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof App'?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to **learn-by-doing** Typescript with React so I've migrated manually from JS to TS in my `create-react-app` but my default testing file `App.test.ts`:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  render(<App />); // There's an error here
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

has this error:

```
'App' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof App'?
```

Comment: You need to use the `.tsx` file extension to enable JSX parsing.

Comment: But this is not a React Component, it's a testing file.

Comment: Sure, but `<App />` isn’t valid javascript, it’s JSX. You need to use the `.tsx` file extension to tell typescript to parse it as JSX and transform it to a call to `React.createComponent`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `.tsx` for `JSX` and `.ts` for non-jsx files. This is because you are using `.ts` extension for files with JSX. To resolve this, change the file extensions from `.ts` to `.tsx` for any files that contain any component code and logic.  This enables the `<App/>` to be parsed as JSX and not regular JavaScript/TypeScript. Worked for me.